# Unable to save/open pdf file in R

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and I am trying to learn it. So, please bear with me if this question is silly!

I am trying to execute the below code in RStudio and I get the following error:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) -- "Dark and Stormy Night"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]

> x=rnorm(100)
> y=rnorm(100)
> pdf("Figure.pdf")
**Error in pdf("Figure.pdf") : cannot open file 'Figure.pdf'**
> plot(x,y, col="green")
> dev.off()
null device
```

I am unable to save or open the pdf file. I tried t o check my permissions and I also ran the Rstudio with administer rights but no luck!

Comment: Are you trying to create a pdf of your x-y plot or do you have a file called `Figure.pdf` somewhere that you wish to read?

Comment: Try `pdf(file = "Figure.pdf")`

Comment: Thanks I think the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

One can direct the output of R graphics functions to PDF files through the use of the `pdf()` function.

The `file =`  argument is a named argument (versus a positional argument), and therefore one needs to use the name in order to change its value. The reasoning for this is that the PDF device function's default value for `file =` allows multiple PDFs to be written, per the R documentation for [pdf()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.2/topics/pdf).

```
x=rnorm(100)
y=rnorm(100)
pdf(file = "Figure.pdf")
plot(x,y, col="green")
dev.off()
```

...produces a PDF in the current R working directory that contains the following image.

[image]